# Are there any “sugars” for Espresso which add brace/bracket highlighting to JavaScript editing?

Tags: applications, development

By “brace/bracket highlighting” I mean: when you select an opening or closing curly brace or a bracket while editing JavaScript in [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/), the brace/bracket you’ve selected and its corresponding closing brace/bracket is highlighted with some visual cue (bold, background colour, anything).

If not, would it be possible to develop such a sugar?

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you mean by “bracket highlighting”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is not. Developing such a Sugar might not be possible from my (very limited) understanding of the Espresso plugin documentation – [JavaScript text Actions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140607074547/http://wiki.macrabbit.com:80/index/JavaScriptActions/) look like the best match, but the API does not seem to offer the kind of access needed for automatic highlighting. Note I haven’t delved into the ObjectiveC plugin docs (because there are none – the headers included with Espresso are the docs, and my understanding of ObjectiveC and Cocoa is slim, to say the least).

Comment: + 1 hey kopischke, I thought as much, just wanted to get a second opinion. thanks